# Access struct field in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table:

```
field1 (STRING), field2(STRING), field3(RECORD)
```

**field3** contains three fields:
**fieldA(STRING)**
**fieldB(STRING)**
**fieldC(STRING)**

I can access *fieldB* by:

```
select field3.fieldB from 'dataset.table'
```

An example table can be

```
field1 (STRING), field2(STRING), field3.fieldB
"AAA"            "BBB"           {"key1":"text1","key2":"text2","keyN":"textN"}
"CCC"            "DDD"           {"key1":"text1","key2":"text2","keyN":"textN"}
```

Now I would get this result:

```
field1 (STRING), field2(STRING), result
"AAA"            "BBB"           ["text2,textN"]
"CCC"            "DDD"           ["text2,textN"]
```

I am using **SPLIT** function to get an array and access it by index, but sometimes I get error because element at index 1 is located at index0 and viceversa. So using *where* clause to compare strings. How can I get this output?

Comment: What is the data type of `field3.fieldB` ?

Comment: @dikesh it's STRING

Comment: You can try this to extract values from JSON: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_value_array

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
select field1, field2, 
  [json_value(field3.fieldB, '$.key2'),
  json_value(field3.fieldB, '$.keyN')
  ] as result
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want one of the values back as string, and using them as individual columns, I would use JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_scalar).

Example:

```
select JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(fieldB, "$.key1") as key1
from 'dataset.table'
```